# NSMutableArray add element not working

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have a `NSMutableArray` and add a new element to it. But apparently it is not added. What am I doing wrong here? Any hints? However, when I run this program for a second time, it works properly.

## Code:

```
NSMutableArray *badgesEarned;

badgesEarned = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSArray *loadedBadgesEarned = [defaults valueForKey:@"badgesEarned"];
badgesEarned = [(NSArray*)loadedBadgesEarned mutableCopy];
NSLog(@"start loaded badges: %@",badgesEarned);

NSArray *type = @"typeABC1";
[badgesEarned addObject:type];
NSLog(@"handleBadge type: %@",type);
NSLog(@"handleBadge result: %@",badgesEarned);
```

## Console output - 1st run:

```
2015-04-24 12:55:12.664 appName[5206:607] start loaded badges: (null)
2015-04-24 12:55:12.664 appName[5206:607] handleBadge type: typeABC1
2015-04-24 12:55:12.664 appName[5206:607] handleBadge result: (null)
```

## Console output - 2nd run:

```
2015-04-24 13:16:58.133 appName[5305:607] start loaded badges: (null)
2015-04-24 13:16:58.133 appName[5305:607] handleBadge type: typeABC1
2015-04-24 13:16:58.133 appName[5305:607] handleBadge result: (
    typeABC1
)
```

## additional info:

`NSLog(@"start loadedBadgesEarned: %@",loadedBadgesEarned);` gives:

### 1nd run:

```
2015-04-24 13:57:35.473 appName[6090:607] start loadedBadgesEarned: (null)
```

### 2nd run:

```
2015-04-24 13:57:49.418 appName[6090:607] start loadedBadgesEarned: (
)
```

Comment: and if you log the `loadedBadgesEarned` array?

Comment: I added it (see additional info)

Comment: and `defaults` is the same in both runs?

Comment: try this too: insted of `badgesEarned = [(NSArray*)loadedBadgesEarned mutableCopy];` try `[badgesEarned addObjectsFromArray:loadedBadgesEarned];`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding [Javito_009](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3996954/javito-009) comment, instead of:

```
badgesEarned = [(NSArray*)loadedBadgesEarned mutableCopy];
```

using following fixes the issue:

```
[badgesEarned addObjectsFromArray:loadedBadgesEarned];
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not storing the array back to the user preferences, at least you are not showing any code for it.

At some point you have to write

```
[defaults setObject:badgesEarned forKey:@"badgesEarned"];
```

BTW. You are creating a mutable array unnecessarily. Just write

```
NSMutableArray* badgesEarned = [[defaults valueForKey:@"badgesEarned"] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: Indeed, I am using `[defaults setObject:badgesEarned forKey:@"badgesEarned"];` later on, but thats not the problem.

Using `NSMutableArray* badgesEarned = [[defaults valueForKey:@"badgesEarned"] mutableCopy];` directly doesn't help solving the problem though…